# React | Error Passing Default Props Values When Destructuring Assignment is Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, react-context

My understanding is there are a few ways to pass default values to a prop in React.

However, none of the ones I tried seems to mitigate my issue.

Essentially I'd like to have a default value to prevent undefined values to break the app completely.

i.e React App with `useContext()` hook

```
const context = useContext(FarmContext)

// destructuring assigment 
const { fruit = 'foobar' } = context.data.farm[0] // apple


*****
<Compoment fruit={fruit} /> // apple
```

**My problem:**

If there is a mistake/typo when chaining the data above on either:
`cooontext` or `dattta` or `farm[55]`

The app breaks with `cannot read property ________ of undefined`

Therefore my destructured fruit = 'foobar' never kick is in place.

```
// does not work if there's a typo on object chaining
const { fruit = 'foobar' } = context.DA23ta.farm[0] // farm is undefined

*******
<Compoment fruit={fruit} /> // app breaks
```

Additionally, I've tried passing the default prop value approach:

```
// does not work if there's a typo
const { fruit } = context.DA23ta.farm[0] // farm is undefined

*******
<Compoment fruit={fruit || 'foobar'} /> // app breaks
```

I've also tried passing `defaultProps` as an alternative but I cannot mitigate this issue either.

The *only* scenario I got this to somewhat work is when I structure the data as:

```
const fruit = context.data.farm[0].fruuuit // big typo at the end here


// prop will render as 'foobar' bellow
<Compoment fruit={fruit || 'foobar'} /> // foobar
```

I'd like my code to have a fallback value no matter what happens to the data (typos, values that become undefined overtime).

I'd like that fallback default value to be **at** the destructuring assignment.

How can I add a preventive defensive strategy when if there's a typo/break anywhere (**not just at the very last chained object as I show above**) within:

`const { fruit = 'foobar' } = contExt.dAta.farMM[0]`

How could I still win on the other side and **return** `foobar` as the fruit prop and not have my entire app break because of one undefined prop?

Is this possible or doable at all? I'm open to other strategies (if there's any) that I have not shown here.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need something like Ramda's [pathOr](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pathOr). Which will return the value by given path, if value exists otherwise return provided default value.

```js
const data = {
  context: {
    data: {
      farm: [
        { fruit: 'apple' },
        { fruit: 'orange' }
      ]
    }
  }
}

const getFruit = R.pathOr('foobar', [ 'context', 'data' , 'farm' , 0, 'fruit' ])
const getFruitWithTypos = R.pathOr('foobar', [ 'contExt', 'dataaaa' , 'form' , 0, 'fruuuuuit' ])

console.log(getFruit(data))
console.log(getFruitWithTypos(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's very interesting. Thank you for posting that. Though big bummer that this cannot be accomplished natively with JavaScript (?)

Comment: @NullisTrue Well, there is "native" approach called optional chaning proposal which you can use right now, for example with babel plugin github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining. But it's only in stage 1 and may not be included into ES standart. Also it requires small changes in syntax from simple `.` to `?.`

Answer (score 0):

### Optional chaining to the rescue!

Optional chaining is [fairly well supported now](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining)

```js
const context = useContext(FarmContext)

// destructuring assigment 
const { fruit = 'foobar' } = context?.data?.farm?.[0] ?? {} // apple


<Component fruit={fruit} /> // apple
```

Also, you can use [`defaultProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) if you can.